# Are Oxygen shortages possible in closed bivouacs?

Tags: sleeping, night, bivouac

I used to think this question was a bit ridiculous. The volume of air that we take in while breathing may be high but the lungs [only consume 25% of the oxygen](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9066318) for any breath and the rest is returned. Closing the windows while sleeping in a room or sleeping in a closed tent does not affect one's breathing. (At least, it never did for me and I have never heard of such a case.)

However, when I tried my new [bivouac sack](https://www.outdoorresearch.com/ch_en/helium-bivy.html) (measures 2.1 m long, 66 cm wide, 50 cm high) last weekend there was a point during the night where I experienced some unrest. I could not sleep (which is not that unusual when it is cold) but also my breathing became very heavy and shallow. More surprisingly, when I opened the bivouac sack's door, the breathing relaxed immediately. I did some background research on this and from [this calculation](http://members.shaw.ca/tfrisen/how_much_oxygen_for_a_person.htm), it seems that humans consume one cubic meter of air in half a day. So if we break this down to a quarter cubic meter for 6 hours of sleep, it might come close to the volume of air that was available in the sack. (But then again I still can't believe it.)

In the end, I left the door a bit opened for the whole night. However, I do not think this is solution will always work.

**Now I wonder, was what I experienced mainly psychological or are oxygen shortages while sleeping in a bivouac a real thing?**

Additional background that may or may not inform answers to the question: The temperature was about 0 °C (32 °F), the air was humid (rather foggy, close to a river) and the elevation was at 500 meters above sea level. I went to stay in the bivouac at 7 pm, the breath shortages occurred, I think, around midnight.

Comment: Just an FYI for your research until someone answers: the gas that matters when discussing respiration like this is CO2, not oxygen. CO2 is what controls your body's breathing systems.

Comment: So you are saying, it is not about depleting oxygen but about accumulating CO2 in the bivouac?

Comment: yes, that is the idea

Comment: Did you ever suffer anxiety attacks in the past? Did you have a big day ahead of you that you planned as if it were the moon landing? If it didn't reoccur I doubt it is psychological, but then I'm an engineer :) None the less, very interesting!

Comment: Never suffered from anxiety attacks or breathing shortages before (and never since). I am a healthy, optimistic person in my mid 20ies and often in the outdoors. The trip should rather be compared to your average Sunday-stroll. Its main purpose was to test the new bivouac sack and I was accustomed to the environment and situation - with the exception of the new bivouac and maybe the fact that it was unusually cold.

Comment: Rather than linking to a wiki page about bivi sacks, why don't you link to your actual product.

Comment: I thought about that but did not want to be advertising concrete products. Anyway, here you go: The bivy is the Helium Bivy from Outdoor Research - https://www.outdoorresearch.com/ch_de/helium-bivy.html

Comment: Alpkit found this to be a real issue. https://www.alpkit.com/develop/bivvy-bag-development

Comment: Incidentally, on oxygen content: the air we breath is 21% oxygen, and the air we exhale is 16% oxygen. So the difference is 5 percentage **points**, not 5%. It's actually more like 25%, going from 21 to 16.

Comment: If it is that air tight then you are also likely to get a lot of condensation.

Comment: @ Pete Becker: Thank you, very good point. I will edit this into the question so it does not mislead people. @Paparazzi: Yes, condensation was quite a problem. At the time, I still did not want to open the bivouac during the night for additional ventilation because it was very cold. (So cold that the condensed water on the inner walls of the bivouac was frozen when I woke up the next morning.)

Comment: Sounds like you have a summer only bivouac.

Comment: Correct. Or in other words: I chose (one of) the lightest version I could find, the sack weighs just 500 gram which naturally translates to less isolation power and probably also to less breathability of the material. (I intend to use it for light weight multiple-day trail-running trips, but we're getting off-topic here I guess.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you put a plastic back over your head, you are going to suffocate. A good bivvy bag should be designed such that suffocation is not an issue. However, breathing into a bivvy bag is a terrible idea because the vapour in your breath will condense and make you wet.

Make this question a non issue by not breathing into your bivvy bag. Leave an opening. Check the manufacturers recommendation on your product. I bet it gives the same advise.

Andy Kirkpatrick has talked about a time when he was bivvying in Patagonia in a special bag made by Rab Carrington. The bag had a 'snorkel' of sorts to allow for breathing. During sleep Andy had a suffocation experience because the snorkel had collapsed. Sorry i dont have a link to this.

Answer (score -1):

I would not have guessed you could deplete O₂ or saturate CO₂ but evidence that you can.

You compared to a tent. A typical backpacking / climbing tent design is different.  The walls and ceiling are breathable with a rain-fly over the top.  Even a 4 season tent is breathable.

[image: without rainfly] 
[image: with rainfly]